# sudoers file change not working?

Tags: shell, sudo, sudoedit

I'm in Ubuntu 18.04LTS and I want to change the sudoers file to execute `sudo shutdown -h now` without the need of password (for `my_username`). The steps I take were:

With my user `my_username` open terminal:

`sudo visudo`

The line I added:

`my_username    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`

Where there is only one tab in the first part (between user and ALL) and the rest are spaces.
The user is the one it appears after `id` in terminal.
After that, just in case I restart the system, and type `sudo shutdown -h now` but it keeps asking for password.

What I'm doing wrong?

-----EDIT------

Ok, I didn't know that the order in which you add the lines were important, so as asked I added my full file (it's a very simple sudoers config).

```
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
my_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This way it works perfectly for me. The problem was that I added the line after root line.

Comment: Where is your `shutdown` binary located? Try `command -v shutdown` in a shell.

Comment: It also shows `/sbin/shutdown`

Comment: this line `my_username    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown` should be after `username ALL=(ALL) ALL`.

Comment: Oh, so I have to add first `my_username   ALL=(ALL) ALL` in one line and in the next line `my_username   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown` ?

Comment: I added the answer, yes, but if you could provide this config section of your `sudoers` file in your question, we can help more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in sudoers man page ([man 5 sudoers](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)) has been mentioned

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.
>   Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not
>   necessarily the most specific match).

So no matter if your config is specific.

Also consider if you have `sudoers` group ( like `wheel` in Red Hat based distros) the line

`%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL` should be before `NOPASSWD`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration

```
my_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

allows the user `my_username` to run `/sbin/shutdown` with or without arguments and without giving a password, but they must use `/sbin/shutdown`, not just `shutdown` (as what executable is picked up would depend on the `$PATH`).